# AngularJS search on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form where I want the user to be able to enter in search terms into textboxes, and then click a button to search the list.  Is it possible to do something like this with ng-repeat and a button click?  I'm really new to Angular, and I'm unsure if I can use it for this type of functionality.  I have a little bit of code:

HTML

```
<div>    
<input ng-model="filterSearch.address" />
<input ng-model="filterSearch.city" />
<button ng-click="">Search</button>    
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Address 
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
        <tr ng-repeat="search in vm.searches | filter: filterSearch">
            <td>
                {{ search.address }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ search.city }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {   
'use strict'
angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', AdvancedSearchCtrl);

function AdvancedSearchCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.searches = [
               {
                   "address": "202 This St",
                   "city": "Columbus"
               },
               {
                   "address": "205 That St",
                   "city": "Dayton"
               }

    ];


}
})();
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.  Thanks.

Updated code:

```
<div>    
<input ng-model="searchModel.address" />
<input ng-model="searchModel.city" />
<button ng-click="filterSearch = searchModel">Search</button>    
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Address 
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
        <tr ng-repeat="search in vm.searches | filter:{'address': filterSearch.address, 'city': filterSearch.city}">
            <td>
                {{ search.address }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ search.city }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify fields to search on like:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="search in vm.searches | filter:{'address': filterSearch.address, 'city': filterSearch.city">
        <td>
            {{ search.address }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ search.city }}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And if you *need* the on-click to trigger the search, you can just use something like:

```
ng-click="filterSearch = searchModel"
```

And change your inputs to use the `searchModel` variable.

Comment: Ok.  I updated my code in my question to reflect the changes you have suggested.  I'm doing something wrong though, because it's still searching the list when I type it into the textboxes instead of only searching and displaying when I click the button.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show me some code?  I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: If it's only happening after the first click, it's because the filterSearch object is set by reference to the searchModel object, rather than the values being copied. Just do `filterSearch = angular.copy(searchModel)`

Comment: where do I put that at?  I've got this?  <input ng-model="searchModel.address" />
    <input ng-model="searchModel.city" />
    <button ng-click="ilterSearch = angular.copy(searchModel)">Search</button>

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really bad with Angular.  :)